# Creating XML node with null value in php

Tags: php, xml, null, nodes

I am creating a xml file using php.
The resulting XML is.

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <firstname>Peter</firstname>
    <insertion>V</insertion>
    <lastname>John</lastname>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </data>
</xml>
```

But in case where a value is null the resulting xml is (**look at node insertion**).

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <firstname>Peter</firstname>
    <insertion/>
    <lastname>John</lastname>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </data>
</xml>
```

**If a value is null I want the xml to be created such that it results in.**

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <firstname>Peter</firstname>
    <insertion></insertion>
    <lastname>John</lastname>
    <gender>Male</gender>
  </data>
</xml>
```

This is my code.

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $root = $doc->createElement('data');
    $doc->appendChild($root);
    $data = $doc->createElement('data');
    $fname = $doc->createElement('firstname');
        $fname->appendChild(
                $doc->createTextNode($row['firstname']));
        $data->appendChild($fname);

        $ins = $doc->createElement('insertion');
        $ins->appendChild(
                $doc->createTextNode($row['insertion']));
        $data->appendChild($ins);

        $lname = $doc->createElement('lastname');
        $lname->appendChild(
                $doc->createTextNode($row['lastname']));
        $data->appendChild($lname);

        $gender = $doc->createElement('gender');
        $gender->appendChild(
                $doc->createTextNode($row['gender']));
        $data->appendChild($gender);
       $root->appendChild($data);
 $doc->save($path . "test.xml");
```

I am sending this xml as response after creating it. So in client side the **lastname** node is becoming a subnode of **insertion**  when it is

```
  <insertion/>
```

Comment: Seems the same thing... it's the shorthand alternative. I don't if it would produce the same result in PHP.

Comment: @codingbiz: could you be more specific. couldnt understand what you meant

Comment: both <insertion/> and <insertion></insertion> are the same.

Comment: Your code didnt work for me.

Comment: @V0R73X: Its working for me. Cant understand why its not working for you. I may be missing something. Actually my complete code is very long so i only posted a part of it.

Comment: have you tried:  $doc->createTextNode(($row['insertion']) ? $row['insertion'] : 0));

Comment: @salexch: I tried it but still it is <insertion/>

Comment: @V0R73X: I have fixed the code. Now its working. Is there any way to create nodes as <node></node> other than <node/> when value is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's being output by default is called "shorthand format".  It's perfectly valid XML, and any properly-implemented XML parser should be able to cope with it just fine.  The only reason why I can think of for forcing "longhand" output is if you have to feed the outputted XML into a parser that's buggy and can't handle the shorthand case.  If you can replace the problematic parser with a working one then I'd recommend doing that instead.

If you absolutely have to output the non-shorthand version, then the DOMDocument::SaveXML() and DOMDocument::save() methods do let you configure their output. A flag can be set that will cause the output to be verbose instead of shorthand.  It's not well-documented in the PHP manual though.  The following code should illustrate how it works.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument ();
$dom -> loadXML ('<root><foo>foo</foo><bar></bar><baz>baz</baz></root>');

var_dump ($dom -> saveXML ());
var_dump ($dom -> saveXML ($dom, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG));
```

Honestly though, I don't think there's much point to doing this if the parser intended to deal with your XML isn't buggy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I suppose using another parser will solve my problem.